# wsl alternitives for mac

Tags: command-line, macos

how do i use a VM or something else like wsl without GUI on my mac terminal only.

CPU: m1
model: m1 macbook air

os: macos ventura 13

vm os i need: Kali linux

Answer (score 0):

Press Command-Space, and type in "Terminal".

If you truly want to boot into a terminal-only experience, it used to be that you can hold Command-S to boot into Single-User (terminal) mode, but I do not know if that option is still available on the latest-and-greatest hardware.

If you want a full Linux VM rather than a POSIX/BSD shell, you can install e. g. VirtualBox and on that VM install whatever Linux OS you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run Kali as a VM, VirtualBox or VMWare are probably the easiest solutions. Both will install a GUI, but you don't need to use it. VirtualBox has [VBoxManage](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html) command, VMWare has [vmrun](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Fusion/13/com.vmware.fusion.using.doc/GUID-FF306A59-080E-497E-857D-F45125927FB3.html). Both solutions have pretty comprehensive documentation.